# How to add custom css file by code?

Tags: 7, theming

Well I know that I have to use `drupal_add_css` like described [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=drupal_add_css).

But that doesn't work and I don't understand why.

I tried to use this hooks: function hook_init, hook_views_pre_render, hook_preprocess_html and hook_preprocess_page.

I tried in that hooks this code:

```
$css=drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/style.css');
$variables['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
```

or:

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/style.css');
$variables['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
```

or also just the first line.

also:

```
drupal_add_css("/".drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/style.css');
```

or that:

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/style.css',
               array('group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 'every_page' => TRUE));
```

Here is my style.css:

```
#logo {
    display:none;
}
```

That should hide the logo on success. What is wrong with my tries?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: That cache located at admin/config/development/performance? Multible times.

Comment: Can you put your function here?

Comment: could use a little more information on what isn't working -- have you used firebug / developer tools before? I've found this to be helpful in the past for debugging drupal_add_ issues. Check the 'resources' / 'elements' tab in these tools and look for where this file is 404'ing to see where its failing. If its not there, the problem is probably in your surrounding hook.

Comment: @schnippy I don't know why but the reason was the name of the file. After I changed the filename the file was included to the sourcecode. Btw. I use firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `hook_init`, removing the first slash should solve the problem. If not, check for permissions.

```
drupal_add_css("/".drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/style.css');
```

Should be

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/style.css');
```

Comment: No sorry that doesn't work. Like I wrote above I tested all variations. That one above is just the currient try.

Comment: In hook_init write an exit command to see whether the hook is called or not.

Comment: If I uncomment the line above (`die('<a href="/'.drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/style.css">test</a>');`) I'll get a link to my css file.

Comment: The problem seems to be the name of the css file. If I change it to blah.css everything works. I'll accept your answer anyway because you pointed to the small error in my example above.